# Pexpect does is not synchronized with firewall prompt

Tags: python, expect, firewall, pexpect, pxssh

I am trying to get data from a firewall using Pexpect module (More specifically, pxssh). The login process is okey and the problem comes exactly in the `i` assignment line:

```
if i==2: # password or passphrase
            self.sendline(password)
            # Up to here, everything is okay#
            i = self.expect(["(?i)are you sure you want to continue connecting", original_prompt, "(?i)(?:password)|(?:passphrase for key)", "(?i)permission denied", "(?i)terminal type", TIMEOUT])
```

This is the firewall's dialog when a user is logged in:

> Password:
>
> Last login: Mon Sep 25 06:20:50 2017 from IPXXXX
>
> Number of failed attempts since last successful login: 0
>
> admin@DEVICE(active)>

I think the problem is that Pexpect don't expect these two lines of Last Login and Number of failed attempts, so the code execution is stopped in the line I said before.

Shell that the firewall uses:

```
admin@DEVICE(active)>
```

Init code of my pexpect class:

```
def __init__(self, host, user, password):
    str = 'ssh '+user+'@'+host
    self.user = user
    self.child = pexpect.spawn ('ssh '+user+'@'+host)
    self.child.expect ('Password:.*')
    self.child.sendline (password)
    self.child.expect (user+'.*>')
    ...
```

)

Comment: i'd suggest you use `pexpect` other than `pxssh`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using pexpect, I have to write more code but it solves my problem,, However, I have this topic open to try to get an answer for future projects.

Comment: what shell is it using in the remote firewall after you login? could you post the code you use for the login?

Comment: Sure, I update it in the topic.

Comment: i mean the pxssh code you are using for the login since the question is about pxssh problems.